# Is it possible to programmatically launch the php interactive shell from a file?

Tags: php, phing

I would like to be able to either launch php in interactive mode via phing or via PHP (worst case scenario, phing can run an adhoc task with the desired code).

I've gotten this far:

```
<?php
  $cmd = 'php -d auto_prepend_file=bootstrap.php -a';
  passthru($cmd)
```

And the above almost gets me what I want. I enter a shell I can interact with, but the prompts are gone (the `php >` at the start of each line), all meta-commands (e.g., `\>`) totally fail, and typing `exit;` does nothing instead of exit the shell. So, as you can see, this isn't the ideal shell. Is this even possible without installing phpsh?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [PsySH](http://psysh.org) will give you want you want. It's a PHP REPL that gives you the option to [configure](https://github.com/bobthecow/psysh#psysh-configuration) it to automatically include a bootstrap file.

Comment: I figured this wasn't possible. Thanks though, this should do what I want.